# How do I disable user password request to shut down from retropie?

Tags: authentication, remote

I am a newb to Ubuntu/Linux. I am running Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS with retropie.  Whenever I try to shut down the system from retropie it always asks for a password and I have to plug in a keyboard and enter the password.

How do I disable the password request so I can shut down easily from retropie?

A simple step by step would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you using a terminal command to shutdown or a gui method? Would you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/974041/edit) your answer with how you are shutting down and any errors from commands you have run?

Answer (score 3):

Edit your box's `sudoers` file. In a terminal run `sudo visudo`. `visudo` does a good job of limiting the damage that can be done by manual edits. Adding the following lines, replacing `bob` with the correct username. Running the above command with `sudo` requires the current user's password.

```
Cmnd_Alias SHUTDOWN_CMDS = /sbin/poweroff, /sbin/halt, /sbin/reboot
bob ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: SHUTDOWN_CMDS
```

If your system is not connected to the Internet in anyway, an alteritive is to change the line `sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL` to `sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`. If connected to the internet this is risky.

The `sudoers` file alters `sudo` permissions to allow a specified user or group to run specific commands. In this case bob can run various shutdown commands without a password.

> The `/etc/sudoers` file controls who can run what commands as what
>   users on what machines and can also control special things such as
>   whether you need a password for particular commands. The file is
>   composed of aliases (basically variables) and user specifications
>   (which control who can run what).
>   -  Ubuntu Community Wiki -
>   [Sudoers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers).

Comment: That's not working.. Do I need to have root access? If so how do I get root permissions?

Comment: OK found some corruption so reinstalled everything and that worked!  Thank you !!

Comment: If you would post an answer to your question stating the steps taken to resolve your problem, then mark the best answer as accepted others will be better able to find the solution.

Comment: Is there a reason why you did not add `/sbin/shutdown` to that alias?

Comment: I was not trying to make a comprehensive alias just a function example. When you find questions and answers that can be improved all users even unregistered users are encouraged to improve them by editing. Feel free to submit an edit to include the additional alias.